# Fish terminal + iTerm, only run shell integration if terminal is iTerm

Tags: iterm2, fish

iTerm has a shell integration script that enables some fancy features, as in having the ability to scroll up to last prompt (in case if there was a lot of stdout i.e. when compiling some code).
However if the terminal is not iTerm, that shell script fails and pollutes the prompt.

I'm trying to clean it up as in only run the shell integration if the terminal is iTerm.

Comment: It should be treated as a bug, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting this in your ~/.config/fish/config.fish should do the trick

```
if test $TERM_PROGRAM = iTerm.app
    test -e {$HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.fish ; and source {$HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.fish
end
```

Comment: This does not work once you log to another host with ssh as the TERM_PROGRAM variables is not defined anymore. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Putting this in your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` should do the trick **and** check for `$TERM_PROGRAM` having been set.

```
test -n "$TERM_PROGRAM"
and test $TERM_PROGRAM = iTerm.app
and test -e {$HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.fish
and source {$HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.fish
```